# R character string methods

Tags: r, string

Say I have a strings

```
seq1 <- "ACTACTGGATGACT"
pattern1 <- "ACT"
```

What is the best way to find the number of times the pattern is in the sequence, in R?  I would like to use a sliding window for loop, but im not clear on the proper way to handle the character strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(seq1, pattern1)
#[1] 3
```